# Why is the result of my query only outputting one row?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I am disabling dates in a jQuery UI date picker from my database and the code I have is almost working, the only thing is that it is only reading one row from the database. At the minute I have two bookings in the database so there should be two separate bookings in the date picker where days are disabled but there is only one. Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

```
     <?php
    $bookeddates = "SELECT fromdate, todate FROM messages WHERE listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'";
        $resultbookeddates = mysql_query($bookeddates) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $bookeddates);
        $date_list = array();
        while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) {


            $from = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['fromdate']));
            $to = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['todate']));

            $start_time = strtotime($from);
            $end_time = strtotime($to);
            $date_list[] = $from;

            $current_time = $start_time;

            while($current_time < $end_time) {
                //Add one day
                $current_time += 86400;
                $date_list[] = date('Y-n-j',$current_time);
            }

            $date_list[] = $to;   

       } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookedDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_list); ?>;
</script>
```

Resolved, the problem was actually what was being stored in the JavaScript variable. Code above reflects the working code.

Comment: How can you tell only one row is fetched? You fetch all the rows, one by one, and keep overwriting $from and $to. After you've fetched all the rows, you only use the last $from and $to in the rest of the code.

Comment: Are you able to verify that just running the SQL query returns two rows? Can you try just that? Or try outputting each ``$rowbookeddates`` in your while loop. Also ``mysql_fetch_assoc`` has been deprecated. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @kainaw - I am able to tell as in the database I have two rows with different dates and only one of the rows dates are being disabled. How can I resolve only using the last $from and $to in the rest of the code?

Comment: how many records are you waiting using this `listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'"` ?

Comment: @Jeff - Yes, when I run the query in MySQL Workbench there are 2 rows returned. Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that. I am aware that it is deprecated but I will be converting to MySQLi & worrying about security when I have everything working :)

Comment: @Alex - There should be two records at the minute

Comment: so look to everybody's answer - you have looped to get just last one

Comment: @Alex - How do I resolve this though? I have changed my while statement to include the processing code as suggested by gibberish but this hasn't worked.

Comment: so do you know how many records your query return? did you do echo? what is the result you have so far?

Comment: @Alex - If I echo $from & $to before the last closing } I get the two records returned

Comment: what? what do you mean by *last closing }* ?? you should `echo '+1+'` right after `while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) 
{` and count that echo!

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what you mean by echoing '+1+'. The code I have at the minute is basically what gibberish posted below.

Comment: I mean `echo '+1+';` literally

Comment: Apologies, I see what you are doing now. +1+ is displayed twice

Comment: update your code in your post, and show the result you have so far

Comment: I have now updated the code above

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure where your while loop parens should go, but you need to move them down.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $bookeddates = "SELECT fromdate, todate FROM messages WHERE listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'";
        $resultbookeddates = mysql_query($bookeddates) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $bookeddates);
        while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) {
            $from = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['fromdate']));
            $to = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['todate']));

            $start_time = strtotime($from);
            $end_time = strtotime($to);
            $date_list = array($from);

            $current_time = $start_time;

            while($current_time < $end_time) {
                //Add one day
                $current_time += 86400;
                $date_list[] = date('Y-n-j',$current_time);
            }

            $date_list[] = $to;

    }

    $date_list_res = '["' . implode('","', $date_list) . '"]';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookedDays = <?php echo $date_list_res; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: upvoted, just because this is exact answer for the posted question, even if using an array with unknown number of unordered and unsorted elements (dates) looks very weird and useless to me :-)

Comment: @gibberish - Thanks for this, I have just tried it but I am still only getting one row output

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) 
{
  $from = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['fromdate']));
  $to = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['todate']));
}
```

traverses the resultset, assigning its values to $from and $to, replacing the previous value. When the loop finishes, you get the "from" and "to" values for the **last** record traversed.

You should either put the results in an array for further processing, or include the processing code inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was trying to say -- +1

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio - Thanks, I have tried including the processing code inside the while loop but that doesn't seem to have worked :/ How would I go about putting the results in an array?